# Modify Shopify Brooklyn product page

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

I´m sort of new with Shopify and I just selected the Brooklyn theme for my future shop. One of the problems that I´ve found is that, when you have more than one product picture, those show up right below the main picture vertically aligned (as you can see in this example: https://themes.shopify.com/themes/brooklyn/styles/brooklyn/preview ) which makes it a bit tedious from an User experience point of view.
Also, one of the problems I have found is that when you add different product variants (for example different colours), instead of showing pictures of only the color selected by the user, they show all the product variants pictures alltogether, which is not ideal.

This shop sort of managed to repair the issue with the pictures displaying vertically but not the one with pictures of both variants showing alltogether (http://www.tajerandi.com/collections/pants/products/open-secret?variant=8337048067).

This guy seemed to properly address both issues that I would like to resolve as you can see https://publicrecapparel.com/products/all-day-every-day-pant?variant=3625257732 
He hides pictures of products variants that are not selected by the user and he also presents thumbnails with more pictures way better than by default.

Does anyone has faced a similar issue??

Comment: This is not the issue but features of  this theme. Try to read more about this theme and you will get the same funcionality.

Comment: This feature requires a lot of tweaking and customizing the product page. I don't know if any of the themes available have this kind of feature set in place. publicrecapparel page uses JS to rotate the images, while loading all the images at the same time.

Comment: I´ve been reading quite a lot about the template and also trying to find a solution in the shopify forum, as this topic is addressed by several users as you can see here for example: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/change-product-photos-to-thumbnails-under-main-image-in-brooklyn-theme-272292 . I know is not a simple task and probably requires a lof of modifications ...

Comment: I´ve found this link ( https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/42c2566cedfd85698d6c#file-product-liquid ) that in theory addresses one of the problems, which is to hide the product variants thumbnails that have not been selected by the user, but I don´t really know how to put it in practice. Is it just a matter of adding those lines to the respective files?

Comment: If you can comment on how many products you have in mind to use this feature I might be able to help you.

Comment: Well I want all the products from my shop to be represented with that layout... This tutorial addresses my issue but using a different theme so I havent been able to successfully apply it to my site http://littlesnippets.ca/blogs/tutorials/15665261-grouping-images-with-variants